# Grep and replace fuzzy pattern of string

Tags: python, regex

I have a few files with python code and decorators like this:

```
@trace('api.module.function_name', info=None, custom_args=False)
```

The only difference between these decorators is the string 'api.module.function_name' - func name and module are different. And depending on the this param name sometimes this decorator is one-lined, some times it is two- or three-lined.

I want to replace these decorators with the other one - more simple, like "@my_new_decorator".

I thought about some regex but I have no idea if it's possible for such "fuzzy" search. I tried `^@trace([A-Za-z0-9]\, custom_args=False)$`
But it doesn't work.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Well a regex like that wouldn't work, you'd need something more like `^\s*@trace\(.+\)$` because you're matching one alphanumeric character and only matching at all if this is all at column 0.

Comment: you might need the multiline flag in your regex : `re.M`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(\n|^)\s*@trace\(\s*'[^']*',\s*info=None,\s*custom_args=False\s*\)\s*(\r|\n|$)
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wU7zK5/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use `^@trace\('api\.(.+)\.(.+)', info=None, custom_args=False\)$` with a multiline flag.

You may want to use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) :

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile('^@trace\('api\.(.+)\.(.+)', info=None, custom_args=False\)$', re.M)
>>> re.sub(pattern, '@my_new_decorator('\1', '\2')', '@trace('api.module.function_name', info=None, custom_args=False)')
@my_new_decorator('module', 'function_name')
```

See [this](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NzIGSGobeLVuPdBj) for the demo of the regex

As you can see `\1` expand to the first group in the regex `(.+)`